# Diagnosing Execution Timeouts from simple actions?

Tags: sql-server, iis, sql-server-2016, windows-server-2016

How can I diagnose why I'm getting so many `Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation` errors today? I do not want to increase execution timeouts.

The first one ocurred in Sql server management studio by editing a row (ie. right-clicking the table in Object Explorer and Edit Top 200 Rows). This has happened several times today with a table of 10K rows.

The 2nd one popped up from an asp.net web app, where the stored procedure returns a row from a 5K-row table.

How can I diagnose this and see if there's a bottleneck between my work PC (the client) and the server where the database resides? Or maybe it's an issue with the database?

Edit: I don't know if it's a coincidence, but I just ran a query in the server's SSMS to see if I could reproduce the issue directly in the server. After doing this I'm not getting any more timeouts in my client PC.

[image]
[image]

Comment: More than likely your action is blocked and waiting on a resource. You would start to diagnose this with a separate connection and using `sp_who2` or the far more detailed 3rd party `sp_whoisactive`

Answer (score 0):

If the two error are not related, you can check the second error by type more logs before or after the error line and try to find more information about the error. You can check the logs in visual studio directly or check the logs by "Logging" module of IIS.

But it seems the two errors are related and may be caused by same reason. So you can use third party software `sp_whoisactive` as Stu mentioned in comment. You can also use [Redgate](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-monitor/) to diagnose sql.